# Going in flags and Enabling WebGL

Tags: webgl

It says that WebGL is disbled. How do I enable it? I looked in the chrome flags. The option "Disable WebGL" is enabled. How do I disable the option?

Comment: Your question is sort of broad.  We don't even know what browser your asking about.

Answer (score 0):

If *Disable WebGL* is enabled, then WebGL is disabled. To enable it, you have to disable disabling WebGL. Just click *Disable* below the flag.